# Matrix for a Complex linear map, am I doing it right?

Tags: matrices, linear-transformations

here's what I have to do:

Let

$f: \mathbb{R}^2  \to \mathbb{C} : f(x, y) = (x - iy)$

$g: \mathbb{C}  \to \mathbb{C}^2 : g(z) = (2z - \overline{z}, z - 2\overline{z}) $

$h: \mathbb{C}^2  \to \mathbb{R}^2 : h(z1, z2 ) = (Re\{z1 + z2\}, Im\{z1+z2\})$

Determine the matrix for $h \circ g\circ f$.

I'm having problem with finding a matrix for $g$ and $h$. I suspected (not sure anyway) that a basis for C could be just

$\{1\}$

And therefore $g$ could be associated with

$g(1)^t = (2 - 1, 1 - 2)^t = (1, -1)^t $

And moreover, for $ \mathbb{C}^2 $ I thought to use the basis:

$\{(1,0), (0,1)\}$

Since:

$h( 1, 0)=  (1, 0)
$

$h(0,1) = (1, 0)$

The corresponding matrix should be:

$\left(\begin{array}{cc}
1 & 1 \\
0 & 0  \\
\end{array}\right)$

At the end of the day the matrix I'm looking for should be the product of the three matrices, resulting in $(0, 0)$, which I don't think is correct.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just compute:

- $g\bigl(f(x,y)\bigr)=g(x-iy)=\bigl(2(x-iy)-(x+iy),(x-iy)-2(x+iy)\bigr)=(x-3iy,-x-3iy)$,
- $h\bigl(g\circ f(x,y)\bigr)=h(x-3iy-x-3iy)=\bigl(\operatorname{Re}(-6iy),\operatorname{Im}(-6iy)\bigr)=(0,-6y).$

Thus the matrix is $\;\begin{pmatrix}0&0\\0&-6\end{pmatrix}$.

Answer (score 0):

Note that\begin{align}h\bigl(g\bigl(f(1,0)\bigr)\bigr)&=h\bigl(g(1)\bigr)\\&=h(1,-1)\\&=(0,0)\end{align}and that\begin{align}h\bigl(g\bigl(f(0,1)\bigr)\bigr)&=h\bigl(g(-i)\bigr)\\&=h(-3i,-3i)\\&=(0,-6).\end{align}So, the matrix of $h\circ g\circ f$ with respect to the standard basis of $\mathbb{R}^2$is $\left(\begin{smallmatrix}0&0\\0&-6\end{smallmatrix}\right)$.

Comment: Does it mean that if I'm OK considering $\mathbb{C} $ as the scalar field, my matrix should be exactly the one I found?

Comment: @Bafforasta No. The scalar field must be $\mathbb R$.

Comment: how do I establish that? (sorry for the question, that may sound dumb)

Comment: @Bafforasta The composite function maps $\mathbb R^2$ to $\mathbb R^2$.

Comment: @amd I had realised this already, just a few moments after posting the comment.

Comment: @Bafforasta Please mark one of the answers as the accepted one.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos, I'm trying to solve my very last doubts, then I'll certainly close the topic marking one as correct

Answer (score 0):

Since neither $\bar z$ nor the real/imaginary parts in $h$ are $\mathbb C$-linear operations, you'll need to treat $\mathbb C$ and $\mathbb C^2$ as *real* vector spaces of dimension 2 and 4, respectively.

Once you do that, it's just a matter of writing down the matrices and multiplying them out. (Or, as Bernard and José suggest, simply running each of the standard basis vectors of $\mathbb R^2$ through the entire chain of transformations, after you've convinced yourself that the composition is indeed linear).

Comment: What basis should be used in the case? is it fine just $\{(1,0),(0,1)\}$ for $\mathbb{C}$ as 2-dimension vector space on $\mathbb{R}$ and $\{(1,0,0,0),(0,1,0,0),(0,0,1,0), (0,0,0,1)\}$ for $\mathbb{C}^2$? (I missed the class about this and my book doesn't really specify it, I'm having then difficulty to figure out)

Comment: @Bafforasta: I would write the bases as $\langle 1,i\rangle$ for $\mathbb C$ and $\langle(1,0),(i,0),(0,1),(0,i)\rangle$ for $\mathbb C^2$.